# Is it better to store data in multiple rows or just in one json in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, json, rdbms, nosql

Once such example for this can be the question bank for a user and test. There can be a lot of relation that can arise in future.

When user attemps questions in a set there are multiple random number of question.
So while submitting that set it is good to store data of a particular set as json or multiple rows

**Approach 1**

**QuesTable**

```
id | ques
```

**UserTable**

```
id | username | setinfo
```

Where setinfo can be stored as json for a particular user for any number of sets he create,
when user creates a set we can append the data in this json.

```
{
  "sets": [
    {
      "set1": [
        {
          "q1": {
            "given_answer": "a",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          },
          "q2": {
            "given_answer": "c",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          },
          "q3": {
            "given_answer": "b",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "set2": [
        {
          "q1": {
            "given_answer": "a",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          },
          "q2": {
            "given_answer": "c",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          },
          "q3": {
            "given_answer": "b",
            "some_key1": "some_value1",
            "some_key2": "some_value2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**APPROACH 2**

Its same but we can create another table for set info and store each set as its own id

**QuesTable**

```
id | ques
```

**UserTable**

```
id | username
```

**user_set_table**

```
id | userid | setinfo
```

Here every time user creates a set it will create a new column in user_set_info and using FK userid
where each setinfo is

```
[
  {
    "q1": {
      "given_answer": "a",
      "some_key1": "some_value1",
      "some_key2": "some_value2"
    },
    "q2": {
      "given_answer": "c",
      "some_key1": "some_value1",
      "some_key2": "some_value2"
    },
    "q3": {
      "given_answer": "b",
      "some_key1": "some_value1",
      "some_key2": "some_value2"
    }
  }
]
```

**APPROACH3**

**QuesTable**

```
id | ques
```

**UserTable**

```
id | username
```

**User_Set_Info**

```
id | userid | quesid | given_ans | somekey1 | somekey2
```

Here the issue is if user gives a test that has 100 question so it will create 100 rows and needs 100 insertion tough the query can be single.

Is it a good idea to make multiple rows ? When should be best to use json in mysql column and when not?

Comment: Reasons with down vote could have been appreciated ..

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize. For a Relational Database - if the information is *ever* anything less than an 'opaque block' it works best to normalize it. Without correct normalization it is not possible to write SARGABLE queries or enforce direct referential integrity. (Some RDBMS engines allow sharding of JSON/XML, but that's another can..)

Comment: Also, the number of columns in SQL should be fixed (there are some problems for which is this an exception, but again: advanced use only) just as the members of a class are fixed. SQL multiplicity works across rows.

Comment: As far as 'which technology to use'; that is generally outside the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions you should ask yourself are:
- Is the data easy to retrieve?
- Is the data easy to update?
- What is my data's durability if I change the model later?

Relational databases answer these questions with:
- SELECT
- UPDATE
- ALTER and UPDATE

When using a JSON storage, you may have trouble to alter the data, reducing drastically the durability of your database, and making it way more difficult to maintain.

When taking your decision about data storage, always think [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)